# Verify JWT token signature of custom created tokens

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, json-web-signature

I am new to PHP (Laravel), i am using `tymon JWT library`.
I generated a custom token, now i want a way to verify its signature knowing that the token is not going to be extracted from `header` or `request` object it is like a stand alone token `ex:eyJ0eXAiOiJK.eyJzddSwsd.C1PCr4D`

I am using `JWT tokens` for other purposes than authentication,
so this method of validating credentials wouldn't help or `middlewares`

```
    if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Response::json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
```

Comment: Not finding the answer here? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication `JWTAuth::setToken('foo.bar.baz');`

Comment: I don't need to set a token, i already have one and need to verify/validate its signature

Comment: Yeah, well how do you do that? By passing (i.e. setting) the token and then using the lib to validate that value. "Of course you can also manually set the token aswell, as needed if there are other entry points into your application. e.g."... And then the authentication code is right below that... `JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()` and then cases for the responses, invalid, expired, etc

Comment: That lib is very tied to Laravel authentication. If you want a looser integration maybe look at https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt and use `JWT::decode`.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!